# Ignore login failed for user run_time error message to SQL Server by VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba

I connect to SQL Server and I have no problem but what I want to do when I enter wrong login username or password ignore the run_time error message and show my msgbox. Can anyone help me please?

This is my code

```
Sub mylogin()

    u = Forms!pass!n1
    p = Forms!pass!n2

    If db.State = adStateOpen Then db.Close

    If Forms!pass!n1 = u And Forms!pass!n2 = p Then

        db.ConnectionString = "driver={sql server};" & _

       "Server=user-pc;" &"Database=profiles;" &"Uid= u ;" &"Pwd= p "

        db.Open , u, p

    Exit Sub

Else

     MsgBox " incorrect username or password", vbCritical + vbOKOnly

Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into error handling. There's some good doccumentation out there for you to look at on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx).

Long story short, you'll need an `On Error ..` statement, and probably something to go with it. Assuming all of your code is right, you'll want to do something like the following (replace `9999` with whatever error code you're looking to replace).

```
Sub mylogin()
On Error GoTo Handler
    u = Forms!pass!n1
    p = Forms!pass!n2
    If db.State = adStateOpen Then db.Close

    db.ConnectionString = "driver={sql server};" & _
           "Server=user-pc;" &"Database=profiles;" &"Uid= u ;" &"Pwd= p "
    db.Open , u, p

    Exit Sub

Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9999
            MsgBox "Incorrect username or password", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            MsgBox Cstr(Err.Number) + ": " Err.Description
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks  for your help I try this code it stop the run-time error but the msgbox does not appear

Comment: What run time error were you getting before? Did you put that error number in place of the `9999` case statement?

Comment: the number of run-time error is to long '-2147217843(80040e4d)': when I wrote it give syntax error on code

Comment: I've updated the `Case Else` portion of the error handler to display `Err.Number` and `Err.Description`. What number shows up now?

Comment: it dose not running  its mention to error on msgbox

Comment: I had an error in my code, I apologize. I believe that I have fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I try this update and its working

Sub mylogin()

On Error GoTo Handler

```
u = Forms!pass!n1
p = Forms!pass!n2
If db.State = adStateOpen Then db.Close

db.ConnectionString = "driver={sql server};" & _
       "Server=user-pc;" &"Database=profiles;" &"Uid= u ;" &"Pwd= p "
db.Open , u, p

Exit Sub
```

Handler:

```
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 9999
        Exit Sub
    Case Else
       MsgBox "Incorrect username or password", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
End Select
```

End Sub

Comment: Note that your code catch all errors and return the same message for all of them (excepted the 9999 one), which could be misleading if the error is not because of a wrong login/password couple.